# Inserting new rows into an existing table

Tags: php, performance, mysql

I want to insert about 10000 new rows into an existing table which already contains 10000 rows. I need to get the `insertid` for the query and to use that `id` in another function inside the loop.

```
foreach($values as $val){
   $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_posts (`post_author`, `post_date`, `post_content`, `post_title`, `post_excerpt`, `post_status`,`post_modified`,`post_type`)
   VALUES('".$val[author]."',NOW(),'".$val[content]."','".$val[title]."','".$val[excerpt]."','published',NOW(),'post')";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $insertid = mysql_insert_id();
   add_post_meta($insertid, $val[metakey], $val[metaval], true );
}
```

I am fetching the values for the `$values` array from a CSV file. As of now, I can insert only 20 new rows per 3 minutes. Is there any way to speed up this insertion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I continue, the following must be said:

## Stop using `mysql_query`.

Seriously.  There have been very good replacements for going-on a decade now.  And considering this code does not appear to escape anything at all, you'd do well to learn to use parameterized queries so that it doesn't have to.

---

With all that said, though, the SQL might not even be necessary.  Is there a good reason you're not using [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) to, well, insert a post?  Looks like it lets you set everything you want to set, and then some.  It also returns the post ID, so you don't even have to touch the database directly to get it.

It sounds like the problem is not SQL or WordPress, really.  This code should not be as slow as you're describing.  If you have a DB server that's not your web server (which is generally the case in shared hosting and such), there will naturally be a bit of slowdown.  Generally not *that* much delay, though, unless the DB is hosted in a totally different place (ie: not from your web hosting company).  That, and the possibility that the server (DB or web server, either one) is simply overloaded, are more likely possibilities.

Comment: I have tried with wp_insert_post but same result as I said then I have replaced wp_insert_post with mysql_query()

Comment: @ArunVKumar: `mysql_query` is about ten steps backwards.  Regardless, though, it's not really the SQL or WP that's causing things to be slow.  Hold on...

Comment: this is the actual code http://pastebin.com/NTRzMRBu

Comment: @Arun: You do realize this is "Code Review", right?  Posting your real code in the question is pretty much *the whole point*.  Truth is, though, this sounds more like a problem for SO.  If the code is *abnormally* slow, that's more a bug than an optimization thing.

Comment: Sorry cHao.. It was possible 900 insertion into wp_posts table as the data in the wp_posts increased its dropped into 30-40 insertions to wp_posts table

Comment: First I thought it may be due to the so much function calls in the wp_insert_post function. So I replaced my code with the one I posted above in this post.

Comment: It's almost certainly not the `wp_insert_post` calls.  WP does a bit more DB stuff than strictly necessary, but not enough to cause the degree of slowdown that you're seeing.  How was the table created?  You let WP do its five minute install thing, or create the tables yourself?

Comment: wp did table creation

Comment: And your web server and mysql server...are they the same machine?  On the same network?  Or are they in two different places?  (Simplified a bit: what does the hostname param look like?)

Comment: i am trying this on local server. So web server and mysql server are on same machine!!

Comment: So yeah.  Unless your machine is overloaded, things should not be as slow as they are.  I'd expect at least a few dozen posts a second even on a slow machine.  Sounds like there's a problem with something else here besides the code.

Comment: Could you able to test tht?? I will provide you the necessary files..

Comment: I don't use WP, so i don't have an install handy to set up a test in.  Lemme see if i can scrounge up a site to put one in, though.

Comment: the problem comes only when there is 2000+ entries in wp_posts table..

Comment: I just created the site...i don't have 2000 posts.  :)

Comment: may i send you the files to create the 2000 posts?

Comment: I have increased the max_execution_time for php script. Still the problem exists..

Comment: unzip the file and place in wordpress root folder and access the script import-csv.php through browser.

Comment: I just ran the script four times from the command line...even starting with 2600 posts in the database (from thr first three runs), the script still runs the fourth time at about the same speed as the first time.  Whatever performance problems you're having are not due to the code.